# How to install ursina on pydroid?

Tags: python, android, ursina, pydroid

Hello I am trying to make minecraft using ursina on Android
And once I tried to install ursina this error happend

```
To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

Comment: How are you installing `ursina`?

Comment: Using pip in terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't support Android. From the website:

> Platforms
>
> - Windows
> - Linux
> - Mac

Comment: Aww man :( I just wanted to make a game on android